# Modal pops up after Ajax call completes instead of before or during

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to get a modal popup to show "Please Wait" while an Ajax call is being made. The pop up occurs only after the call completes.

When I click my web link, everything is working, except the modal popup that is supposed to say "Please Wait" flashes for a split second AFTER the delay that the user is supposed to be asked to wait thru. That is, the modal pops up AFTER the Ajax call is completed instead of before.

When the page loads, it calls **AjaxInitialUpdate**. This works fine.

The issue is when you click the button that calls **AjaxChangePassword**.

The function is supposed to pull up a modal, then contact the web server, before finally removing the model and calling the **AjaxInitialUpdate** function to refresh the whole screen.

The issue is that the **AjaxChangePassword** modal doesn't pop up until the web query completes (by which time, there is no point in telling the user -- Please Wait).

Now, I am totally self-taught here, so I may be calling things by the wrong name or terms. I welcome any ideas to make it run better, but please be detailed, I'm still very novice in Java.

Also, the last time I did any kind of HTML programming was before Style sheets were the way to go, so I'm kind of having to learn them as well (and refresh on all the rest, so please explain any answer in detail).

Lastly, the server side of this is written in Powershell and is single threaded so I am trying to put as much in the HTML file as possible instead of calling secondary files, like style sheets and images.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<head>    
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">    
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />    
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />    
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
<style>    

body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}    


/* The Modal (background) */    
.modal {    
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */    
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */    
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */    
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */    
  left: 0;    
  top: 0;    
  width: 100%; /* Full width */    
  height: 100%; /* Full height */    
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */    
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */    
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */    

  /* Believe these are not needed.
     Imported from web site that I copied the code from.
  padding: 8px 8px;    
  outline: none;    
  border: none;    
  border-radius: 115px;        
  box-shadow: 0 3px #999; */    
}    


/* Modal Content */    
.modal-content {    
  background-color: #fefefe;    
  margin: auto;    
  padding: 20px;    
  border: 1px solid #888;    
  width: 70%;    
}    

/* The Close Button */    
.close {    
  color: #aaaaaa;    
  float: right;    
  font-size: 28px;    
  font-weight: bold;    
}    

.close:hover,    
.close:focus {    
  color: #000;    
  text-decoration: none;    
  cursor: pointer;    
}    


#IndividualSystem {    
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;    
  border-collapse: collapse;    
  width: 100%;    
  border: 1;    

}    

#IndividualSystem td, #IndividualSystem th {    

  text-align: left;    
  padding: 8px;    
  color: black    
  border: 1px solid black;    
}    


#IndividualSystem tr {    
  padding-top: 12px;    
  padding-bottom: 12px;    
  text-align: left;    
  background-color: #eeeeee;    
}    

.tab { margin-left: 40px; }    

.button {    
  display: inline-block;    
  padding: 8px 8px;    
  font-size: 12px;    
  cursor: pointer;    
  text-align: center;    
  text-decoration: none;    
  outline: none;    
  color: #fff;    
  background-color: #4CAF50;    
  border: none;    
  border-radius: 15px;        
  box-shadow: 0 3px #999;     
}    

.button:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}    

.button:active {    
  background-color: #3e8e41;    
  box-shadow: 1 5px #666;       
  transform: translateY(4px);    
}    

.button2 {    
  display: inline-block;    
  padding: 8px 8px;    
  font-size: 12px;    
  cursor: pointer;    
  text-align: center;    
  text-decoration: none;    
  outline: none;    
  color: #fff;    
  background-color: #000080;    
  border: none;    
  border-radius: 15px;        
  box-shadow: 0 3px #999;     
}    

.button2:hover {background-color: #df330e}    

.button2:active {    
  background-color: #FD2E02;    
  box-shadow: 1 5px #666;       
  transform: translateY(4px);    
}    

#IndividualSystem {    
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;    
  border-collapse: collapse;    
  width: 100%;    
  border: 1;    

}    

</style>    

<Title>Cyber Track</title>    
</head>    

<body>    
<table>    
    <tr>    
        <td>blah</td>    
        <td><h1>Systems and Passwords</H1>    
        <h3>Information within this page is considered confidential.</h3>    
    </td></tr>    
</table>    

<hr>    


<input type="hidden" id="Leftlink" name="Leftlink" value="0">    
<input type="hidden" id="Rightlink" name="Rightlink" value="0">    
<input type="hidden" id="serverID" name="serverID" value="server8\admin-server8">    
<input type="hidden" id="count" name="count" value="10">     <!---  Number of servers per page on server list //-->    

<!-- The Modals #1 -->    

<div id="myModal1" class="modal">    

    <!-- Modal content -->    
        <div class="modal-content">    
            <h4><label id="ModalTextLine1">Loading content from server</label></h4>    
        </div>    
</div>    

<!-- The Modals #2 -->    
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">    
    <!-- Modal content -->    
        <div class="modal-content">    
            <span class="close2">&times;</span>    
            How long do you need the password?    

                <form action='#'>    
                <select name="days">    
                <option value='1' >1 day or less</option>     
                <option value='7'>between 1 and 2 days</option>     
                <option value='7'>between 2 and 7 days</option>     
                <option value='30'>between 7 and 30 days</option>     
                <option value='365' selected>for up to a year.</option>     
                </select>    
                <br>    
                <input type="submit" value="Process Request">    
            </form>    
        </div>    
</div>    

<script>    
// Get the modal    
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');    

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal    
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close2")[0];    

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal    
span.onclick = function() {    
  modal2.style.display = "none";    
}    

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it (or actually, just hide it)    
window.onclick = function(event) {    
  if (modal2.style.display != "none")    
  {    
    if (event.target == modal2) {    
        modal2.style.display = "none";    
    }    
  }    
}    
</script>    

<!-- End Loaded from function -->    

<table id="IndividualSystem">  <!-- IndividualSystem - to define needed style sheet //-->    
<tr>    
    <td style="width: 215px;">Server</td>    
    <td style="width: 259px;"><label ID="DynServerName">Loading</label></td>    
</tr>    
<tr>    
    <td style="width: 215px;">User ID</td>    
    <td style="width: 259px;"><label ID="DynAdminID">Loading</label></td>     
</tr>    
<tr>    
    <td colspan="2"><hr></td>    
</tr>    
<tr>    
    <td style="width: 215px;">Checked out status:</td>    
    <td style="width: 259px;"><label ID="DynLastCheckedout">Loading</label></td>    
</tr>    
<tr>     
    <td style="width: 215px;" valign='top' >Last checked out by:</td>    
    <td style="width: 259px;" valign='top' ><label ID="DynLastCheckedBy">Loading...</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
                 <button class="button" onclick="javascript:AjaxCheckOutPassword()" id="PassStatus">Loading</button> <!--  AjaxCheckOutPassword -->    
    </td>    
</tr>    
<tr>    
    <td valign='top' style="width: 215px;">Expected Check In Date:</td>    
    <td valign='top' style="width: 259px;"><label ID="DynExpectedBack">Loading</label></td>    
</tr>    
<tr>    
    <td style="width: 215px;">Date of last password change:</td>    
    <td style="width: 259px;"><label id="DynLastReset">Loading</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="button2" onclick="AjaxChangePassword()">Force Change Now!</button>    
                  </td>    
</tr>    
<tr>    
    <th colspan="2">Notify:<br>    
        <table border="1" padding = "0" width=100%>    
            <tr>    
                <td width=200>On Use:</td><td><label id="DynEmailCheckOut">Loading</label></td>    
            </tr>    
            <tr>    
                <td width=200>On Checkin:</td><td><label id="DynEmailCheckIn">Loading</label></td>    
            </tr>    
        </table>    
    </th>    
</tr>    
<tr><td colspan="2">    
        <label ID="DynAccountPurpose"></label>    
</td></tr>    

</tbody>    
</table>    

<!-- Page Footer (if any) //-->    

<!-- Page links left/up/right //-->    
<table>    
<tr><td width = 50>    
    <label id="Show-Left">    
        <a class='w3-left w3-btn' href='#' onclick="AjaxNavigate(-1)" text='Prior Server'>    
                     <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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' alt='go to prior server' height='26' width='32'>    
        </a>    
    </label>    
    &nbsp;    
   </td>    
   <td>    
            <a class='w3-left w3-btn' href='#' onclick="AjaxNavigate(0)" text='Next server'>Return to main list</a>    
   </td>    
   <td width = "50">    
   <label id="Show-Right">    
        <a class='w3-left w3-btn' href='#' onclick="AjaxNavigate(1)" text='Next server'>    
                    <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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' alt='go to prior server' height='26' width='32'>    
        </a>    
   </label>    
   &nbsp;    
  </td>    
</tr></table>    

<!-- End Page links left/up/right //-->    

<!-- Dynamic JAVA Script Section //-->    

<script>    

// disable our NAV pointers till later where we may re-enable them.    
document.getElementById('Show-Right').style.display = 'none';    
document.getElementById('Show-Left').style.display = 'none';    

//
//  This is the specific function that I need help with.
//  Why does this modal pop up only after the actual query is done?
//    
function AjaxChangePassword(){    

    document.getElementById('myModal1').style.display = "block";    
    document.getElementById('myModal2').style.display = "none";   // Make sure its not poped up..    
    // we need to set item on the modal to explain what we are doing...    
    document.getElementById("ModalTextLine1").innerHTML="Processing password change request.  Please Wait"   

    var xhr = "";    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    

    // server will check if values are valid..    
    var Server = document.getElementById("DynServerName").innerHTML;    
    var AdminID = document.getElementById("DynAdminID").innerHTML;    

    xhr.open('GET', 'http://PSShellSrv.mydomain.local:80/CyberPass3/?command=update&sub=change&server=' + Server + '/' + AdminID+'&NoCache=' + ((new Date()).getTime()), true);    

    xhr.responseType = 'text';    

    xhr.onload = function () {    
        console.log('Initail Comment Response onpassword change.');    
        if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {    
            if (xhr.status === 200) {    
                console.log(xhr.response);    
                console.log("Report password changed.");    
                AjaxInitialUpdate() // password changed, lets refresh.    
            };    
        };    

    };    
    xhr.send(null);    
    document.getElementById('myModal1').style.display = "none";    
};    


// Navigate left and right..    
function AjaxNavigate(link)    
{    

    xx = document.getElementById('Leftlink').value    

    xx = document.getElementById('Rightlink').value    

    if (link == 0)    
    {    
        // Back to the main page.  Get the values that make who we are -- servername and count.    
        var count = document.getElementById('count').value;    
        var CurrentSystem = document.getElementById('serverID').value;    
        var x = '/CyberPass3/?command=homepage&server=' + CurrentSystem + '&count='+ count + '&NoCache=' + ((new Date()).getTime());    

        location.replace('/CyberPass3/?command=homepage&server=' + CurrentSystem + '&count='+ count + '&NoCache=' + ((new Date()).getTime()));    
    }    
    else    
    {    
        if (link == 1)    
        {    
            document.getElementById('serverID').value  = document.getElementById('Rightlink').value    
        } else {            
            document.getElementById('serverID').value = document.getElementById('Leftlink').value    
        }    

        // we've moved left or right.  Lets update.    
        AjaxInitialUpdate()    
    }    

}    

function AjaxCheckOutPassword() {    

                console.log("Checkout Code not yet written");    
};    


function AjaxInitialUpdate() {    
    var xhr = ""    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    var count = document.getElementById('count').value;    
    var link = document.getElementById('serverID').value    
    document.getElementById('myModal1').style.display = "block";   // show we are updating everything..    
    document.getElementById('myModal2').style.display = "none";   // should already be hidden, but lets make sure..    
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://PSShellSrv.mydomain.local:80/CyberPass3/?command=update&sub=refresh&server=' + link + '&count=' + count + '&NoCache=' + ((new Date()).getTime()), true);    
    xhr.responseType = 'text';    

    xhr.onload = function () {    
        console.log('Initail Response.');    
        if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {    
            if (xhr.status === 200) {    

                WebFields = xhr.responseText.split("|");    

                document.getElementById("DynServerName").innerHTML = WebFields[0];    
                document.getElementById("DynAdminID").innerHTML = WebFields[1];    
                document.getElementById("DynLastCheckedout").innerHTML = WebFields[2];    
                document.getElementById("DynLastCheckedBy").innerHTML = WebFields[3];    
                document.getElementById("DynExpectedBack").innerHTML = WebFields[4];    
                document.getElementById("DynLastReset").innerHTML = WebFields[5];    
                document.getElementById("PassStatus").innerHTML = WebFields[6];    
                document.getElementById("DynEmailCheckIn").innerHTML = WebFields[7];    
                document.getElementById("DynEmailCheckOut").innerHTML = WebFields[8];    
                // if no comment, don't even dispay the table cells.    
                if (WebFields[9].slice(0,1) == "{" && WebFields[9].slice(-1) == "}" && WebFields[9] != "{}" )    
                {    
                   var res = WebFields[9].split("{");    
                   var res = res[1].split("}")[0];    
                   document.getElementById("DynAccountPurpose").innerHTML = "<tr><td style='width: 474px;' colspan='2'><p><b>Account Comments:</b></p><p class='tab'>" + res + "</p></td></tr>";    
                   }    
                else    
                {    
                    document.getElementById("DynAccountPurpose").innerHTML = "";    
                    console.log("No Comment");    
                };    

                // lets populate the nav buttons..    
                if (WebFields[10] == '\\')    
                {    
                    // hide go left    
                    document.getElementById('Show-Left').style.display = 'none';    
                    document.getElementById("Leftlink").value = "0/0"    
                }    
                else    
                {    
                    //Enable go left    
                    document.getElementById('Show-Left').style.display = 'block';    
                    document.getElementById('Leftlink').value  = WebFields[10];    

                };    


                // lets populate the nav buttons..    
                if (WebFields[11] == "\\")    
                {    
                    // hide go right    
                    document.getElementById('Show-Right').style.display = 'none';    
                    document.getElementById("Rightlink").value = "0/0";    
                }    
                else    
                {    
                    // Enable go right    
                    document.getElementById('Show-Right').style.display = 'block';    
                    document.getElementById("Rightlink").value  = WebFields[11];    
                };    
                document.getElementById('myModal1').style.display = "none";    
            }    
            if (xhr.status === 403) {    
                console.log(xhr.response);    
                document.getElementById("PassStatus").innerHTML = 'Access Denied';    
            }    
            if (xhr.status === 404) {    
                console.log(xhr.response);    
                document.getElementById("PassStatus").innerHTML = 'Unable to load';    
            };    
        }    
        else    
        {    
            document.getElementById("PassStatus").innerHTML = "Failed";    
        };    
};    

xhr.send(null);    

};    

// Now, load the initial value..    
window.onload = AjaxInitialUpdate();    

</script>
```

When I call **AjaxChangePassword()**, I expected the modal to open BEFORE the query.
As it is now, if I stop the server after the page loads, but before this function is started, the modal never pops up, then once I start the server side back up, and I see the query come in and get answers, only then does it pop up, and then only for a split second.

What am I doing wrong in the way I am calling it?

Comment: Sorry, but that is a LOT of code. Please edit it down to a [mcve], as I for one am not going to wade through it all

Comment: This is because I am lost on where the error actually is. I've been trying to isolate it for days and have already cut significant portions of the page. This is also why my outline gave specifics as to what calls were being made to cause the issue. At the same time, your response makes me feel like I was a fool for even asking for assistance. I'm sorry I am a newbie at this, but we all were at some point. If its not worth your time, I understand. Hopefully, not everyone will share that point of view.
Plus, it's working correctly in one function and not in the other, so I included both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I reviewed your code and found that in the function AjaxChangePassword firstly you opened modal and then called ajax then closed modal the problem is that basically javascript executes synchronously but if there is ajax call then it executes asynchronously, so according to that your modal opens and then call ajax untill ajax is busy in getting response before that next line will be executed that line is for modal close and this happens in the fraction of ms so you don't see anything, And you said that after ajax call modal is showing because in AjaxChangePassword the call back method is AjaxInitialUpdate and also in this method you opened modal then closed but remember in this method you closed modal in the call back method so it appears for some time and you can see so according to me just remove

```
document.getElementById('myModal1').style.display = "none";
```

this line from AjaxChangePassword method below is corrected AjaxChangePassword function

```
    function AjaxChangePassword(){    

    document.getElementById('myModal1').style.display = "block";    
    document.getElementById('myModal2').style.display = "none";   // Make sure its not poped up..    
    // we need to set item on the modal to explain what we are doing...    
    document.getElementById("ModalTextLine1").innerHTML="Processing password change request.  Please Wait"   

    var xhr = "";    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    

    // server will check if values are valid..    
    var Server = document.getElementById("DynServerName").innerHTML;    
    var AdminID = document.getElementById("DynAdminID").innerHTML;    

    xhr.open('GET', 'http://PSShellSrv.mydomain.local:80/CyberPass3/?command=update&sub=change&server=' + Server + '/' + AdminID+'&NoCache=' + ((new Date()).getTime()), true);    

    xhr.responseType = 'text';    

    xhr.onload = function () {    
        console.log('Initail Comment Response onpassword change.');    
        if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {    
            if (xhr.status === 200) {    
               document.getElementById('myModal1').style.display = "none";  
                console.log(xhr.response);    
                console.log("Report password changed.");    
                AjaxInitialUpdate() // password changed, lets refresh.    
            };    
        };    

    };    
    xhr.send(null);  
};
```

and check. I may be wrong but check it.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  Yes, you were right.  
I spent all day yesterday trying to find what was wrong there..  I moved the code into the block in the actual response block instead of after the send.  It makes perfect sense (although the way it acted didn't that it then loaded AFTER the return as if it was in the "OnLoad" block).
Thanks for taking the time..  I can't express enough my appreciation.